# Theoretical Margin Trading Questions

Tags: trading, margin, day-trading

I am just educating myself on margin trading (I have no real desire to try it any time soon) and was wondering if you may help me with a scenario and a few basic questions to see if my logic is correct.

Scenario:

I have a margin account where I can put down 30% and leverage 70% from my brokerage (pretty standard I assume).

I would like to go long on a stock that is trading at $4.00 per share.
I put $10k into my margin account.
I purchase 8,333 shares putting 30% down ($10,000) and borrowing $23,333.
I am willing to lose $5,000 MAX. So I set a stop loss at approx 3.60 (.40 cent loss per share or roughly $3,330 dollars).

1. Is this correct? I assume if the stop loss is executed I have to transfer 3,330 into the margin account to make up for the loss.
2. What if the stock closes the day at 3.95 (0.05c loss per share) do I have settle up with $416 before end of day? Do I have to close out my entire position? Does this depend on the broker? Do I only have to close out if they place a margin call ?
3. What if the alternative happens and the stock closes at 4.05?

Thank you and please let me know if at any point I was unclear.

Comment: You would have to know what the margin maintenance requirement in order to know if you had to add additional money when the stock dropped 40 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct? I assume if the stop loss is executed i have to transfer 3,330 into the margin account to make up for the loss.

No - you would receive $30k for the sale, pay off the loan and have 6,777 left in your cash account

> What if the stock closes the day at 3.95 (0.05c loss per share) do i have settle up with $416 before end of day? Do i have to close out my entire position? Does this depend on the broker? Do i only have to close out if they place a margin call ?

It depends on your *maintenance margin*. Once your equity (the total value of your investment less the margin amount) goes below a certain percentage, you must deposit enough into the margin to get it back to the initial margin percentage.

However, it's unlikely that a 1.25% (.05 / $4) drop would trigger a margin call.

> What if the alternative happens and the stock closes at 4.05?

Then you have stock that's worth roughly $33,750, you still owe $23,333 (plus accrued interest) and have a net unrealized gain of $417.

Note that if you did *not* use margin and instead bought $10k of stock (2,500 shares) with cash, your net gain would be only $125, and $417 = $125/.3 (where .3 is your margin percentage).  It's no conicidence - the leverage multiplies your gains (and losses) inversely proportionally to the percentage that you contribute - so if you contribute 25% and borrow 75%, your gains (ans losses) are 4X greater than if you contributed 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your answers D Stanley. I guess i was confused because i didnt realize what i put down in cash is equity, so any losses can be taken from my equity and leaving the loan balance intact.